# iphone camera used in app to scan (like red laser)

Tags: iphone, xcode, text, camera, scanning

I am working on an app that requires the use of a camera to scan in text.  Basically without getting too detailed, I need to point the camera at something (for my purposes here I will say a license plate) and i need to point the camera at the plate, and have it somehow save the digits into a string within the app.  i guess its similar to Word Lens or red laser where it doesnt actually take a picture, it just scans the view and returns information. i have not been able to find much about this so any help on how to write this kind of code would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The name of the technology is "OCR".  There's a lot of vendors out there, including some with iOS library claims.  You'll probably need to pay to get anything worthwhile.

Comment: @danh I disagree. There are nice and high-quality opensource OCR solutions out there.

Answer (score 2):

This is not barcode scanning. This is called OCR (optical character recognition), and there are some free and opensource libraries available that do this.

For example, [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is a complete OCR engine written in C++ (it has a C++ interface, so it can be easily used from within an iOS app).

The other solution is [gocr](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/), the GNU Optical Character Recognizer. This is supposed to be a standalone program (a command line tool), but I've had success extracting its essential parts into a library (and I used it in an iOS project of mine as well).

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a complete computer vision library. You can implement OCR using it - just google for the adequate documentation and tutorials.